# In python, will converting variables to its own type waste CPU power?

Tags: python, types, int

I'm trying to fetch an int id number from database and some ids are mistakenly stored as string, I'm wondering which of the following way is better:

```
# the first method
new_id = int(old_id) + 1
# second
if isinstance(old_id, str):
    new_id = int(old_id) + 1
else:
    new_id = old_id +1
```

So the question is, does it cost to convert a variable to its own type in python?

Comment: I think the better question is "does it take longer to type-check than to convert a type to itself?"

Comment: And unless you're doing this with millions of values per second, it's unlikely to make any noticeable difference in CPU usage.

Comment: Whichever approach is more or less efficient, doing either of these things will defeat any attempts to leverage duck typing. I would consider both to be bad practice.

Comment: I see no harm in attempting to convert inconsistent input from an external resource into a consistent type.

Comment: If you truly worry about CPU usage on such a nano level then you shouldn't be using Python in the first place. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's check!

```
~/Coding >  python -m timeit -s "id1=1;id2='1'" "new_id = int(id1)" "new_id = int(id2)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.755 usec per loop
~/Coding >  python -m timeit -s "id1=1;id2='1';f=lambda x: int(x) if isinstance(x, str) else x" "new_id=f(id1)" "new_id=f(id2)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.15 usec per loop
```

Looks like the most efficient way is simply doing the `int` conversion without checking.

I'm open to being corrected that the issue here is the `lambda` or something else I did.

**Update:** 
This may actually not be a fair answer, because the if check itself is much quicker than the type conversion.

```
~/Coding >  python -m timeit "int('3')"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.562 usec per loop
~/Coding >  python -m timeit "int(3)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.136 usec per loop
~/Coding >  python -m timeit "if isinstance('3', str): pass"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0966 usec per loop
```

This means that it depends on **how many of your ids you expect to be strings** to see which is worth it.

**Update 2:**
I've gone a bit overboard here, but we can determine exactly when it's right to switch over using the above timings depending on how many strings you expect to have.

Where `z` is the total number of ids and `s` is the percentage of them that are strings, and all values in microseconds,

```
Always check type: (assuming returning int costs 0 time)
.0966*z + .562*z*s

Always convert without checking:
.136*z*(1-s) + .562*z*s
```

When we do the math, the `z`'s and string conversions cancel out (since you have to convert the string regardless), and we end up with the following:

```
s ~= 0.289706
```

So it looks like 29% strings or so is about the time when you'd cross over from one method to the other.

Comment: Using `lambda` in the first command line in the same way you used it in the second should make it fair comparison.